# Can't show the content of /sdcard of my Android phone from Ubuntu's Nautilus or FileZilla via sftp

Tags: linux, ssh

I set up a ssh server on Android using SSH Server by Ice Code App.

- Settings of ssh server:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlbzJ.jpg 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1X4i.jpg  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgT4d.jpg
- Settings of ssh user `t`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHxMT.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/efqVA.jpg

After upgrading from Android 4.3 to 4.4.2,

- sftp from Nautilus or FileZilla in Ubuntu to Android can't read or write the content of /sdcard any more.
- But ssh and scp from terminal in Ubuntu can still read, write and transfer files in /sdcard.

I connect  using the same ssh user `t` in sftp from Nautilus, and ssh and scp from terminal, although why is the ssh prompt  `u0_a116@C6730` rather than `t@c6730`?

If they indeed use the same ssh user, why is there  the difference in read permission?

In ssh to Android, I see the read, write and excecution permissions for "others" users are not allowed:

```
u0_a116@C6730:/ $ ls -l
...
lrwxrwxrwx root     root    1970-01-11 17:07 sdcard -> /storage/sdcard0
...

u0_a116@C6730:/sdcard $ ls -l                                                  
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1980-01-01 00:00 Alarms
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2015-07-22 08:05 Android
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-18 22:41 Cardboard
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-20 19:40 DCIM
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-29 21:22 Download
...
```

I guess my ssh user `t` belongs to the "other" group. but don't know how to confirm that. I couldn't add the permissions:

```
u0_a116@C6730:/sdcard $ chmod -R a+r Download/                                 
Bad mode
```

What does the "Bad mode" error mean?

What are some solutions?

- Can I change file permissions on Android directly? 
  Do I need root? But I heard that rooting my device Kyocera Hydro Icon with Android 4.4.2 isn't possible due to locked bootloader?
- Can I downgrade Android from 4.4.2 to 4.3?
- Can I upgrade my ssh user account to be one level above "others", so as to have write and read permissions? Do I need root? Will that solve the problem, given the difference in read permissions between sftp from Nautilus and ssh and scp from terminal under the same ssh user?

I found a discussion at http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/sdcard-problems-upgrading-android-t2938749
, where the suggestions seem to require root,  right?
Thanks.

Comment: @Firelord: it is android problem. It denied the permissions of read and write for "other" users to the files in `/sdcard`. But I can't change that, is it because of the upgrade of Android from 4.3 to 4.4.2? Thanks for catching the typo. See my update.